# Bandpass filter audio recording using Accelerate framework (vDSP) and Novocaine

Tags: ios, filtering, signal-processing, fft, vdsp

I'm fairly new to signal processing, so please bear with me. I'm trying to implement a bandpass filter to apply to an audio recording obtained from an iPad. The recording has been converted to a Float32 pointer using ExtFile functions and AudioBufferList. The sampling rate is 44100Hz. The recording is about 9 seconds long (that's about 396900 samples) and contains a 2-6kHz chirp and some ambient noise. I need to bandpass filter the recording around the frequency range 2-6kHz in order to find at what point in time the chirp occurs. I have referred to the following resources to create a bandpass filter:

https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP/blob/master/NVDSP.mm

https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP/blob/master/Filters/NVBandpassFilter.m

My question is, can I simply pass in the array of float values for the recording to the bandpass filter above? I have tried this, but I'm not sure if it's working, since it seems to simply decrease the value of every single value in the array. What should I expect to see after passing the recording th

However, I've seen some resources say that I first need to convert the values from time-domain to frequency-domain using a FFT. I've tried the following code to do this using some vDSP functions:

```
- (Float32 *)calculateFFT
{
    // Acquired from http://batmobile.blogs.ilrt.org/fourier-transforms-on-an-iphone/

    int numSamples = _recordingLength; //~9 seconds * 44100Hz ~= 396900 samples

    // Setup the length
    vDSP_Length log2n = log2f(numSamples);

    // Calculate the weights array. This is a one-off operation.
    FFTSetup fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(log2n, FFT_RADIX2);

    // For an FFT, numSamples must be a power of 2, i.e. is always even
    int nOver2 = numSamples/2;

    // Populate *window with the values for a hamming window function
    float *window = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * numSamples);
    vDSP_hamm_window(window, numSamples, 0);
    // Window the samples
    vDSP_vmul(_recordingSamples, 1, window, 1, _recordingSamples, 1, numSamples);

    // Define complex buffer
    COMPLEX_SPLIT A;
    A.realp = (float *) malloc(nOver2*sizeof(float));
    A.imagp = (float *) malloc(nOver2*sizeof(float));

    // Pack samples:
    // C(re) -> A[n], C(im) -> A[n+1]
    vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX*)_recordingSamples, 2, &A, 1, numSamples/2);

    //Perform a forward FFT using fftSetup and A
    //Results are returned in A
    vDSP_fft_zrip(fftSetup, &A, 1, log2n, FFT_FORWARD);

    //Convert COMPLEX_SPLIT A result to magnitudes
    Float32 *amp = new Float32[numSamples];
    amp[0] = A.realp[0]/(numSamples*2);
    for(int i=1; i<numSamples; i++) {
        amp[i]=A.realp[i]*A.realp[i]+A.imagp[i]*A.imagp[i];
        //printf("%f ",amp[i]);
    }

    return amp;
}
```

But I don't understand what is being returned from this function. If I do need to apply a FFT before passing the recording to the filter, what needs to be returned from the calculateFFT function and then passed to the filter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible to perform filtering in the frequency-domain (which would likely require the use of FFT), but the filter implementation you listed perform filtering in the time-domain, that is it would use the float audio recording samples. The result would depend on your filter design parameters.

Comment: @SleuthEye Okay, so the NVDSP functions filter in the time-domain, so I don't need to use FFT. I guess the recording float array must contain some information about the frequency then if the bandpass filter can filter it given a range of frequencies?

Comment: NVDSP transforms the Fc/Q parameters into time-domain coefficients.

Comment: @SleuthEye I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but will filtering in the time-domain produce the results I'm looking for (ie: filter out areas of background noise and not areas where the chirp is playing)?

Comment: Processing the time-domain samples will have an effect on the frequency content. If the background noise is not-overlapping from the chirp (eg. noise in 8-15kHz range), and the filter parameters are selected carefully, then the noise can be filtered out. If the noise and chirp overlap in time _and_ frequency, then it would be harder to filter out noise (although removing the non-overlapping part can still make your chirp easier to identify).